# how to integrate libraries to load third party files in themes drupal?

Tags: theming

I just want to know how to integrate third party files with the drupal theme.

Comment: I would look into the https://drupal.org/project/libraries module

Comment: PHP or Javascript?

Comment: I just want to include css and js files

Answer (score 1):

To use a CSS/JS library with the Libraries module in Drupal, there are a number of steps:

- copy the library to `sites/all/libraries/my-library`;
- Write a small custom module, which informs Drupal that the library is available;
- Add the library where's its needed, e.g. with a `MYTHEME_preprocess_html` hook.

I found a very nice recent tutorial with code samples [here](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/adding-js-libraries-drupal-project-libraries-api).

Comment: i made theme on semantic ui framework. Its on the sandbox project. On the application review they ask me for use libraries to integrate semantic ui files with the theme. Right now i directly used the semantic ui files in the theme.

Comment: Can you define directly? By using the .info file or?

Comment: I define directly but on application review page they advice to use library module to integrate these files but i don't have idea how to integrate this.

Comment: I edited my answer, which will hopefully be of more help to you.